# SQL Server - Master / Detail - get extract exact detail item match

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, relational-database, database-administration

I need help to extract the exact item match from two table. I want from Detail Table  all the order that exists in Temp Detail and Master and Temp Master itemQty are the same.

example: in this case I need the sum of master.Amount for all the order which ItemQty is 3 and the detail table has the exact same value of temp Detail.

**Master**

```
OrderId|      Amount   | ItemQty |Status
------------------------------------------
125    |       36.75   |    3    |  A    |
------------------------------------------
128    |       11.95   |    5    |  A    |
------------------------------------------
```

**Detail contain lot of order detail**

```
------------------------------------------
OrderId|  ItemId    |  Qty  | Price      |
------------------------------------------
125    |     12345 |  1   |  11.00      |
------------------------------------------
125    |     23456 |  1   |  12.75      |
------------------------------------------
125    |     34567 |  1   |  13.00      |
------------------------------------------
```

**Temp Master**

```
------------------------------------------
|OrderId|      Amount   | ItemQty |Status
------------------------------------------
|9999   |       36.75   |    3    |  A   |
------------------------------------------
```

**Temp Detail**

```
------------------------------------------
|OrderId |  ItemId  |  Qty | Price       |
------------------------------------------
| 9999   |   12345 |    1 |   11.00      |
------------------------------------------
| 9999   |   23456 |    1 |   12.75      |
------------------------------------------
| 9999   |   34567 |    1 |   13.00      |
------------------------------------------
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Thank you John Cappelletti, I have not idea how to format it.

Comment: No worries, in the future just higlight the desired text and click the {} button  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this

```
select m.OrderId, sum(m.amount)
from master m
join detail d
on m.OrderId = d.OrderId
join tempDetail td
on m.OrderId = td.OrderId
where m.ItemQty = 3
group by m.OrderId
having sum(d.Qty * d.Price) = sum(td.Qty * td.Price)
```

Comment: Hi Stefano, thank you, the thing is the temp-Master and Master has different order Id, I need where the detail records are the same for both table no matter the two master has different order id or amount.

Comment: Ok, got it. One question: in your example the amount and qty columns on the details tables are exactly matched by the values on the master tables records (like 36.75 = 11 + 12.75 + 13). Is it always the case?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess:

```
select Masterr.OrderId,
       sum(Masterr.Amount)
  from Masterr
 where Masterr.ItemQty = 3
   and exists(select *
                from Detail
                join TempMaster on TempMaster.ItemQty = Masterr.ItemQty
                join TempDetail on TempDetail.OrderId = TempMaster.OrderId
               where Detail.OrderId = Masterr.OrderId
                 and TempDetail.ItemId  = Detail.ItemId
                 and TempDetail.Qty     = Detail.Qty
                 and TempDetail.Price   = Detail.Price)
 group by Masterr.OrderId;
```